# Is there a way to conduct a mySQL search for any word in a data table that is found with Singular and Plural forms?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, full-text-search

So I have about 3 thousand posts in my database and some seem to be too similar or using titles with plurals. First problem is that I don't have the words to focus on. Second, I need to build a list of those terms so I know what to go back into and remove or consolidate. The part that I am most curious about is getting any iterations of words that are plural and singulars. An example of some potential word sets:

- abstract background
- abstract backgrounds
- abstract desktop backgrounds
- abstract desktop background
- abstract mobile background
- abstract mobile backgrounds

etc...

I cobbled together the following - but it doesn't find any word that it hasn't been provided... so i'd like it to be a variable...

```
SELECT post_title,post_type,url FROM posts WHERE REGEXP '[[:<:]]background[[:>:]]*' AND post_type='published'ORDER BY post_title ASC;
```

Comment: This is domething I would not do in mysql, but use a fuzzy matching library in r or python.

Comment: `'[[:<:]]background[[:>:]]*'` -->`'[[:<:]]backgrounds?[[:>:]]'` -- This says that the `s` is optional.  `*` allows for 0 or more of what preceeds it -- but that is a "word boundary".

Comment: Well, seeing as we're only talking about the words background and backgrounds, this seems pretty trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the MySQL manual for full-text search?

See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

**Example full-text Natural Language queries:**

*Getting a score for column texts against a keyword*

```
mysql> SELECT id, MATCH (title,body)
    AGAINST ('Tutorial' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS score
    FROM articles;
+----+---------------------+
| id | score               |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 0.22764469683170319 |
|  2 |                   0 |
|  3 | 0.22764469683170319 |
|  4 |                   0 |
|  5 |                   0 |
|  6 |                   0 |
+----+---------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

*Using MATCH() expressions in select list and where clause*

```
mysql> SELECT id, body, MATCH (title,body) AGAINST
    ('Security implications of running MySQL as root'
    IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS score
    FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST
    ('Security implications of running MySQL as root'
    IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
+----+-------------------------------------+-----------------+
| id | body                                | score           |
+----+-------------------------------------+-----------------+
|  4 | 1. Never run mysqld as root. 2. ... | 1.5219271183014 |
|  6 | When configured properly, MySQL ... | 1.3114095926285 |
+----+-------------------------------------+-----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

REGEX is very particular about the syntax, this will find background with aa space before it. Before and After you can have any kind of text.

If you want more specific text pattern you have to find the exact syntax

> ```
> CREATE TABLE posts
>     (`post_title` varchar(28))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO posts
>     (`post_title`)
> VALUES
>     ('abstract background'),
>     ('abstract backgrounds'),
>     ('abstract desktop backgrounds'),
>     ('abstract desktop background'),
>     ('abstract mobile background'),
>     ('abstract mobile backgrounds')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT post_title FROM posts WHERE post_title REGEXP 'abstract .*background.*';
> ```
>
> ```
> | post_title                   |
> | :--------------------------- |
> | abstract background          |
> | abstract backgrounds         |
> | abstract desktop backgrounds |
> | abstract desktop background  |
> | abstract mobile background   |
> | abstract mobile backgrounds  |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f76704a2a14073b61c8bc63e8d79ee64)*fiddle=cd40c8103ae36b2fa3f327a9bcf178c3)*